# Looping recursively through folders

Tags: 16.04, bash, scripts, filesystem

I am attempting to run a script that will un rar things and add a file to flag the file as "processed" but it throwing exceptions like directory not found and I am unsure why.

```
#!/bin/bash

function recursive {
    if [ -d "$1" ]; then
        for dir in "$1"; do
            if [ -f "$dir"*rar ]; then
                for file in $dir*.rar; do
                    echo $file

                    if [ ! -f "$dir$file.processed" ]; then                                
                       unrar e "$dir$file.rar" "$dir"
                       touch "$dir$file.processed"
                    fi
                done
            fi

            echo $dir

            subs= find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type d=
            if [ "$subs" != "0" ] && [ "$subs" != "No such file or directory" ]; then
                recursive "$dir*/"
            fi
        done
    fi
}

recursive /home/user/Complete/*/
```

Comment: Did you try to run each "module"/part separately to figure out where is the problem?

Comment: Yeah If I run the script without the rar file part it runs through fine, it will recursively run through all sub-directories but the problem is with my rar logic. I am mostly a windows dev so I'm not 100% on if I'm using the wildcard and bash script variables correctly to build the file names. There is no error output besides "No such file or directory"

Comment: Seems quite an overcomplicated solution to perform a simple task.

Comment: The problem ends up being that I end up unraring stuff multiple times with find for example when rars get loaded into the directory and trigger the script so I have like 10 instances of unrar, all unraring the same files.

Comment: @JBurlison I think Jacob means the directory recursion, because the `find` command can do all but two lines of your script in one line. I'll write you an answer later.

Comment: Ah I was unsure of that I guess this just comes down to my inexperience with Bash scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is based on your answer, but it uses `find` instead of going through the filesystem manually.

```
#!/bin/bash

unrar_if_needed()(
    file="$1"
    dir="$(dirname "$file")" # Extract dir name from file path.
    echo "Found: $file"
    if [[ -f "$file".processed ]]; then # Double brackets are better.
        echo "    Already unrared."
    else
        echo -n "    Unraring... "
        if unrar -inul e "$file" "$dir"; then # This if-statement is not necessary, but a nice touch.
            touch "$file".processed
            echo "Done."
        fi
    fi
)

export -f unrar_if_needed

if [[ "$1" ]]; then
    dir="$1"
else
    dir=.
fi

echo "Looking in: $dir"
find "$dir" -iname "*.rar" -exec bash -c 'unrar_if_needed {}' \; # find runs the custom function.
```

Output should look like this:

```
$ script.sh somedir
Looking in: somedir
Found: ./somedir/file1.rar
    Unraring... Done.
Found: ./somedir/file2.rar
    Already unrared.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

function recursive {
    echo "$1"
    for dir in "$1"*/; do
        if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
            echo "Reading Directory for rars: $dir"
            for file in "$dir"*.rar; do
                echo "Found Rar: $file"
                if [ ! -f "$dir"processed ] && [ ! -f "$file".processed ]; then
                    echo "File not unrared. Unraring File."                                
                    unrar e "$file" "$dir"
                    touch "$dir"processed
                    echo "File Processed."
                else
                    echo "File already Unrared."
                fi
            done
            echo "......Going Deeper......"
            recursive "$dir"
        fi
    done
}

recursive /home/user/Complete/
```